# how to pass data into controller opened via $state.go(controller.state)?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I have array of objects.When I click on name it should open md-content page with configuration of the folder. Situation is next:  when I click on name -it opens conf. page with FolderConfigController, but I want to send folder object into the FolderConfigController to work with it.

```
folders = [{name: name1, id:id1},{name: name2, id:id2},{name: name2, id:id2}]
```

listed in lefsidenav:

```
<div ng-repeat="folder in folders" ng-click="vm.openConfigPage()">{{folder.name}}
```

in folderController:

```
vm.openConfigPage = openConfigPage;
function openConfigPage() {
    $state.go('triangular.config');
}
```

FolderConfigController.config:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.components.work')
    .config(moduleConfig);

/* @ngInject */
function moduleConfig($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('triangular.config', {
        url: '/work/folder/config',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/work/folder-config/folder-config.tmpl.html',

        controller: 'FolderConfigController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
    });

}
})();
```

is it possible to make something like:

```
function openConfigPage(folder) {
    $state.go('triangular.config');
    FolderConfigController.folderObject = folder;
}
```

how it works in correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use state params like this:

```
function moduleConfig($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
    .state('triangular.config/:id/:name', {
        url: '/work/folder/config',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/work/folder-config/folder-config.tmpl.html',

        controller: 'FolderConfigController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
    });

}
})();
```

and then when you transition to that state you can set the params

```
function openConfigPage(folder) {
    $state.go('triangular.config', {"name": folder.name, "id": folder.id});
}
```

and the inject $stateParams into the FolderConfigController controller to gain access to the name and id parameters

```
.controller('FolderConfigController ', function($scope, $stateParams){

   console.log($stateParams):

});
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help